# Customized query for desired Report generation in Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

Following is the structure of table

```
column A, column B, column C
value A,  Value B,  Value C1
value A,  Value B,  Value C2
Value A2, Value B2, Value C3
```

Now, I want result to be viewed as 
Result

```
column A, column B, column C
 value A,  Value B,  Value C1
        ,         ,         Value C2
Value A2, Value B2, Value C3
```

So, if Value of Column A and Column B are same and Value of Column C is different then, how can I take out result as above example like, if multiple values of A and B are same but C is different

Comment: Post sample data and desired output based on it in a tabular form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give tags carefully and as per your question.
You have given mysql as well as oracle 11g and oracle10g also.

okay .. this query is very simple in oracle and following query is tested in Oracle database.

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function for this as below -

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN Rn_Cnt = 1 THEN
          Columna
         ELSE
          NULL
       END Columna,
       CASE
         WHEN Rn_Cnt = 1 THEN
          Columnb
         ELSE
          NULL
       END Columnb,
       Columnc
  FROM (SELECT Row_Number() Over(PARTITION BY Columna, Columnb ORDER BY Columnc) Rn_Cnt,
               Columna,
               Columnb,
               Columnc
          FROM Table_Name)
```